# How to make implicit conversion work when wrapped inside Task?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Here is my code. I am not able to return `Task<OkObjectResult>`. I don't want to convert return type to more specific type such as `Task<OkObjectResult>` as it will block me to return another types of results such as `Task<BadRequestObjectResult>` and I can't change the method's signature. It's MediatR's `IRequestHandler`

What I can do to make it work?

```
public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Request, ActionResult>
{
    public Task<ActionResult> Handle(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Task.FromResult(new OkObjectResult(new Response { IsHealthy = true }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FromResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?view=net-5.0) is a generic method, so you can specify the base type as its generic parameter:

```
return Task.FromResult<ActionResult>(new OkObjectResult(new Response { IsHealthy = true }));
```